# GraphiQL works locally but in production the output shows content from base.html (Django project)

Tags: django, graphql, graphene-python

I successfully installed graphene and graphene-django into my project and am able to make queries with the GraphiQL interface in my local environment.

When I deployed my app to production and visited the GraphQL endpoint, the GraphiQL interface is not working and is showing the contents of my base.html in the output section. The "Docs" will not load anything either.

[image: output of graphiql on live app]

There must be something in the production configuration that is interfering with GraphQL but I haven't been able to pin it down yet.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I found out that Django was giving a CSRF verification failure and that was causing the problem.

Updating the GraphQL url endpoint to include csrf_exempt fixed the problem.

original in urls.py:

```
url(r'^graphql', GraphQLView.as_view(graphiql=True, schema=schema)),
```

updated urls.py:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

url(r'^graphql', csrf_exempt(GraphQLView.as_view(graphiql=True, schema=schema))),
```

source: https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-django/issues/61